# How to use where condition in child collection using lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I want to filter data using lambda expression from a list of collection. But data is not filtered properly when using Fromdate and Todate. It only filtered account Id not date.

Here is my lambda expression:

```
  var query = context.Accounts
            .Include(s => s.Sales)
             .Where(a => a.Type == "C" && a.Sales.Count != 0).AsQueryable();

        if (filter.AccountId.HasValue)
        {
          query = query
                    .Where(a => a.Sales.Any(s => (s.AccountId == filter.AccountId))).AsQueryable();

            query = query.Where(a => a.Sales.Any(s => s.TransactionDate >= filter.FromDate.Date && s.TransactionDate <= filter.ToDate.Date));
        }

        if (!filter.AccountId.HasValue && (filter.FromDate.Date != DateTime.Now.Date || filter.ToDate.Date != DateTime.Now.Date))
        {
            query = query
           .Where(a => a.Sales.Any(s => s.TransactionDate >= filter.FromDate.Date && s.TransactionDate <= filter.ToDate.Date));
        }

        return await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I am not totally sure what you are asking, but you may want to replace one or more of your `Any()` calls with `Where()` calls?

Comment: Yes..you are right. because Any() returns all result if any of the condition is true. But i want only if  the specific condition is true then it will return result.